# Difference between two similar looking theorems in group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra

1. > Let $a \in G$ such that $\operatorname{ord}(a)$ is infinite. Then $(a), (a^2), (a^3), \ldots$ are all distinct subgroups of $G$ and hence, $G$ has infinitely many proper subgroups.
2. > Let $G$ be infinite. Then $G$ has infinitely many proper subgroups.

What's the difference between these theorems? Just the possibility that $\operatorname{ord}(a) = n$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$ in the second one?

Comment: Not every infinite group necessarily contains an element of infinite order. Hence the first theorem does not imply the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly the point.  There are infinite groups, all of whose members have finite order.  $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ is an example of such a group.